# Excel Userform Run-Time Error when trying to launch a 2nd time after initial 'Cancel' or close on red 'X'

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Problem: I am building a Userform that has a 'Submit' and 'Cancel' button. I want the entire form to clear any entered data and close the form if the user hits the 'Cancel' button but I also am trying to build in the same functionality if the user hits the red 'X' in the top right corner. I'm unclear where I need to unload the form. I currently have it placed within the `btnCancel_Click()` method and I'm able to launch the form, enter some data and hit Cancel and it will close the form down.

But when I try to re-launch the form a 2nd time I get an error (I attached a picture of that message) that says

> "Run-Time error '-2177418105 (80010007): Automation Error - The Callee (server [not server application]) is not available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may have executed.

If I remove `Unload Me` from `btnCancel_Click()` then the form can close and re-open just fine, but any data I entered the first time will still be on the form and isn't cleared properly. I'm wondering if this is an `Unload Me` error or do I need to reset all form controls when I initialize the form?

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  ' how was the form closed?
  ' vbFormControlMenu = X in corner of title bar
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    ' cancel normal X button behavior
    Cancel = True        
    ' run code for click of Cancel button
    btnCancel_Click
  End If
End Sub
'******************************************************************
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    mbCancel = True
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me

End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Populate values for 2 combo boxes
lastEmp = Sheets("Form_Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Me.cmbBoxEmpName.List = Sheets("Form_Ref").Range("A2:A" & lastEmp).Value

lastBld = Sheets("Form_Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Me.cmbBoxBuildingName.List = Sheets("Form_Ref").Range("B2:B" & lastBld).Value

End Sub
'******************************************************************
Public form As New CheckOutForm
Sub testFormOptions()
'Button pressed within Excel will start program and show the userform
form.Show

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **easiest quick and dirty** solution:

Delete `Public form As New CheckOutForm` from the code. Then add it in the `testFormOptions()`:

```
Sub testFormOptions()
    Dim form As New CheckOutForm
    form.Show
End Sub
```

Some not-that-good VBA books/tutorials would even go a bit like this, but this is brutal:

```
Sub testFormOptions()
    CheckOutForm.Show
End Sub
```

Anyway, now the problem with the predefined values in the form is solved.

---

For the **clean and not-so-easy solution**, consider writing a MVC framework around the form:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form
- [this blogpost](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/) (disclaimer - mine!), which pretty much says what the above link proposes, but it does not have the errors from the question.
- [the old StackOverflow tutorial for UserForms](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Didn't even think about the global aspect of the form. I will check into the MVC framework, thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `Unload`, you destroy the form object. With other words, your (global) variable `form` gets invalid and if you issue a new `form.show`, you get the runtime error.
When, on the other hand, you just `unhide` the form, the form-object stays valid (it's just currently not visible) and all controls keep their value.

Either you do some housekeeping by resetting all controls when a form is displayed (use the `UserForm_Activate`-event), or you have to create a new form-object every time you want to display it (I would strongly advice not to use the name `form` as variable name to avoid confusion).

```
Sub testFormOptions()
    dim myForm as CheckOutForm
    myForm.Show
End Sub
```